# Unity: Can't access Childrens SpriteRenderer.enabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have problems accessing the enabled variable in children of my Player GameObject.
[image]

-Human holds Rigidbody2D, BoxCollider, PlayerController script and Animator

-body and range_attack_body only hold SpriteRenderer

What I want to do:

I want to change the SpriteRenderer of my Player Object when mouse button is on hold. There are SpriteRenderers in body and range_attack_body. Both GameObjects are part of animations.
body.SpriteRenderer is active and range_attack_body.SpriteRenderer inactive during normal motion.
In my PlayerController script I wrote a routine that will trigger an attack animation when mouse button is on hold. In this routine I wanted to change the enabled states of the SpriteRenderers. However nothing is happening, meaning the varibales are not changing during runtime. I already checked if the GameObjects and SpriteRenderers are accessed correctly during Awake() and I can find both renderers in my SpriteRenderer array using debug messages.
On top of that I checked what happens if I add a SpriteRenderer to my Human GameObject. It will appear in my SpriteRenderer array and I have full access to enabled variable meaning I can change them in my routine. So I figured there might be a conflict with body and range_attack_body due to their SpriteRenderers being part of animations. I added Human.SpriteRenderer to an animation and can still change variables.
I have no clue what is going on, please help. Here is some code:

```
public class PlayerController2D : PhysicsObject {

    public float maxSpeed = 7f;
    public float jumpTakeOffSpeed = 7f;
    public float posOffset = 1;

    protected bool flipSprite = false;
    protected bool flipState = true;

    private Animator animator;
    private SpriteRenderer[] spriteRenderers;


    void Awake ()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        GameObject human = GameObject.Find("Human");
        spriteRenderers = human.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer> ();
    }

    protected override void Attack ()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            spriteRenderers[0].enabled = false;
            spriteRenderers[1].enabled = true;

            Debug.LogError("Inhalt:" + spriteRenderers[0].ToString());
            Debug.LogError("Inhalt:" + spriteRenderers[1].ToString());

            animator.SetBool("attack", true); // boolean to start hold animation
        }
        else if(!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            spriteRenderers[0].enabled = true;
            spriteRenderers[1].enabled = false;

            animator.SetBool("attack", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script code is ok, the problem should be elsewhere.

First of all, disable the `Animator` component and run the script: if enabling/disabling the sprite renderers work, than you must look in the animation clips if you have the `Sprite Renderer.Enabled` property anywhere, most probably you'll have it - remove it so you can enable/disable the renderers only via script.

If the script still doesn't work, then the problem is elsewhere (another script which is accessing the `enabled` property of the renderers).

But I'd bet that you're changing the `enabled` property from the animation clips, which supercedes the script due to how the Unity execution order works (animations are always updated after the scripts and before rendering).

Comment: That was it! I had forgotten that I still had the enabled property inside a release animation. After I deleted the clip, my script worked fine. Thanks a lot! :D